# Translate into WP_Query()?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

i'm new to sql query can someone help me translate an sql query to wp query to make it auto run or schedule?

i need to schedule an event on sql but sadly my host didn't allow me to turn on the event scheduler because i'm only using a shared host account.

is it possible to automatically push this query using wp query?

here's my query

```
SELECT title AS ApplicationType,
value AS ApplicationStatus
FROM sfda_rg_form, sfda_rg_lead_detail
WHERE value = 'Pending'
OR value = 'Approved'
OR value = 'Rejected'
```

thanks in advance

Comment: The Codex is documentation, not a function or class. I think you're referring to the `WP_Query()` class.

Comment: oh i see i thought it was called codex also because that's what i use when i google it, thanks anyways

Answer (score 1):

Using `$wpdb` you can just run queries without having to use any special structure. In your case there aren't even variables to prepare. So this would work:

```
global $wpdb;
$query = "SELECT title AS ApplicationType, value AS ApplicationStatus FROM sfda_rg_form, sfda_rg_lead_detail WHERE value = 'Pending' OR value = 'Approved' OR value = 'Rejected'";
$results = $wpdb->get_results($query);
```

If what you're asking is whether or not there's some kind of mechanism in wordpress that allows scheduled tasks that operate outside of the server's cron jobs then I'd say probably not, though I am not 100% positive. Largely because it would require the server being accessed to trigger - in other words, someone needs to load a page for that trigger to happen without it being set specifically in the cron tab, which you have stated is not an option.

So if you were wondering how to run that query using wordpress $wpdb, making use of the connection and config settings - then this would work for you.

If you were asking if you can run a scheduled task in WP outside cron tab, then it would be up to someone else to definitively say.

Update

If you wish to run this only on demand, you can put this in your functions.php file

```
function run_task(){
    global $wpdb;

    $query = "SELECT title AS ApplicationType, value AS ApplicationStatus   FROM sfda_rg_form, sfda_rg_lead_detail WHERE value = 'Pending' OR value = 'Approved' OR value = 'Rejected'";
    $results = $wpdb->get_results($query);

    // do something with the results
}
```

Then call it however you like. Here's an example using $_GET...

```
//in functions.php also include this
if(isset($_GET['run_task']))
{
    run_task();
}
```

now you can run the task by adding the run_task param to the get vars:
http://www.yoursite.com/?run_task

typically params have values, so if you compound with anything else it might be sane to do something like /?run_task=1&foo=bar

...etc

Comment: hi, im kind of new to wordpress query where exactly should i put that? in function.php? i'm asking a query without using a cron jobs btw..

Comment: functions.php would be fine. You should contain it within a function to prevent it from just running every page load. I updated with an example

Comment: great, can i add another query to // do something with the results ?? to fetch data from the created query above...

Comment: or can i add the parameter to Gravity Form field here? https://gyazo.com/367ede64da193f5835731198b2c4cf0b

Comment: I don't know about hooking into gravity forms. As for the other query - yeah you can do whatever you need but I think that's an issue for another question.